# Are Standards Cheaper Than Automatics (Average)

Tags: transmission

When it comes to replacing parts, I've always been under the impression that a standard version of a car is generally cheaper than an automatic; example a standard Honda Civic vs. an automatic Honda Civic.  One of my friends had to pay $3K to replace an automatic transmission and the most I recall paying for a standard was about $600 for a clutch (which included installation).

Someone said the opposite the other day that automatics are much cheaper than standards when it comes to replacement parts, so that's why I'm asking because this is definitely news to me, unless something has recently changed.

On average, for a standard-vs-automatic comparison for a car and replacing parts which is generally cheaper (not always, *generally*)?

Comment: New or second hand? Location is relevant as well, since one region drives way more of one while another region drives way more of the other.

Comment: In this case, new.  But does used vs. new matter?

Comment: Probably, the price of a used car depends partially on it's availability. With new cars, the price can be partially fixed by the brand who build it.

Comment: I didn't downvote your question, but I can imagine someone finding your question lacking specifics might. If you'd make your question more specific I'll try to incorporate that into my answer and upvote your question.

Answer (score 3):

Since you haven't mentioned your region, I can't say anything about the price of the car. A rule of thumb is that if one type (manual vs automatic) is driven by a significantly larger of the local population, used cars of that type tend to be cheaper as well. The local garage will have more experience with it as well, which may help.

The gearbox of a manual transmission is usually somewhat (in some situations: significantly) cheaper than the parts of an automatic. However, a manual transmission has another part that can easily break down and is relatively expensive: the clutch.

A clutch doesn't break often, assuming you know how to handle one. If you've never driven clutch (commonly known as driving 'stick') before, your first manual will wear down rapidly till you got the hang of it. This may take a couple of miles or a couple hundred. Some never learn it properly and keep burning through them.

Answer (score 1):

Bottom line unless you have some type of racing transmission with exotic metals, automatic transmissions cost more to build.

That bring said, the market influence is a major factor. You will find that auto/manual sports cars often charge much more for their manuals. Camero's were known for this since they produced comparatively few manual trans vehicles.